# How do I find out where openssl is saved on my local machine?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

I'm reaching an error when attempting to install Ruby 2.0.0 using RVM and I think it has to do with the fact that I'm not providing the correct path for Openssl. How do I find the correct path?

Comment: you start by figuring out what OS your machine is running, and paste it in the question. On my mac, open a term and type 'which openssl'

Comment: glad to help. mark question as answered then!

Comment: `which openssl` works on *nix machines, including Mac OS. Also, you can try `locate openssl` if you have the "updatebd" service running. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate for more info on locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a term and type at the prompt:

```
which openssl
```

You should get a path back:

```
/usr/bin/openssl
```

That's for my machine. Yours might vary.

Comment: Nice answer. do you also familiar with `Nokogiri` ?